# Creating apps for facebook groups possible or not?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, whitelist, facebook-group

I'm a member of a facebook group that has contests with artists on a weekly basis. There are over 5000 members to this group, fortunately not all of them participate because at the end of each week there is a voting for the favorite/best artwork of that week. And the admins have to manually go through image by image and count votes. Voting is limited to those who participate in the contest, so the artist places their vote as their image description... or part of it anyway.

I wanted to create an app that would retrieve the photo info from the album to build a list of the submitted images and the artists to make counting votes much easier.

I have, in fact, created such an application but it seems it only works on personal profiles and pages... not groups due to the need to be on a "white list". It strikes me as strange when a group is "OPEN" and an app isn't even allowed to read data there, but OK.

My question is if it is possible to get an app on that white list or at least to build an app specifically for a group for this purpose? I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to find any information on this subject. So, I am asking you all here at stack overflow since you all seem to be in bed with facebook in someway. I am just hoping to get a reply from someone that **knows** something rather than guessing or assuming.

The last contest had 325 participants and it was entirely too many for a poll.

I do not know if this topic has already been addressed... I used the search but stack overflow uses Google for a site search and because these topics are paginated Google has indexed results to be on a certain page but when you go there the topic is nowhere to be found... not very helpful...

Anyway, thanks for your time and I would be most appreciative of getting a reply rather than the post just getting buried to the point nobody will see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing for a similar reason.

It appears not:

> *user_groups*
>
> Provides access to the list of groups the user is a member of as the groups connection.
>
> **This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook**
>   **client on platforms that don’t have a native client.**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-profile

If anybody discovers otherwise I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer of whether apps can be built only for groups without short-listing, but here is an alternative solutions.

If the purpose of this exercise is to limit some functionality (or entries) only to those users who are a member of a group, then why not get the "user_groups" permissions from the user, access his groups through the Graph API and flag users as either being a member of the group or not and extend the functionality accordingly. Perhaps you could even limit registrations to only those who are currently members of the group.

Comment: No, it isn't really about limiting functionality, but simply automating the tabulating of votes. If I can read the album I can generate a list, if I can't generate a list I have to manually create a list... and when there are 350 images to scroll through to copy and paste stuff... it gets old fast! Not to mention the high chance that someone changes their vote after you already counted it...

Another possible solution... do you know if the content of a facebook page can be synched with a group's? For instance if someone uploads a photo to a group that it is mirrored to the group's page?